# No hyphenat exceeds line length instead of newline

Tags: hyphenation

When using `\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}` no hyphenation will occur as expected.
However the maximum line length will be exceeded by some words that are normally be hyphenated instead of placing the word in a new line.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3.6cm,bottom=3.6cm,left=3.6cm,right=3.6cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[5]
\end{document}
```

How can one fix this (without manually placing newline expressions)?

Comment: You can use `\sloppy` before the paragraph. For a limited use, there is `sloppypar` environment.

Comment: The problem is that if latex would put these words onto the next line, there would be too much space between the words on the current line. You can use `\usepackage{microtype}` which will help to some extent, but won't solve all problems.

Comment: Set the text `\raggedright`.

Comment: @Gilean0709 isn't there a way to ignore justification on that line? (again without placing expressions manually on such lines)

Comment: something like ignoring justification on actually hyhenated words + auto insert a newline to keep the maximal line length

Comment: @Buni I don't know a way of ignoring justifaction on a single line without any commands and I don't know if your idea is possible. I don't have enough experience with changing something like that.

Comment: What's the reason for removing hyphenation?

Comment: @egreg When using `\autoref{eq:}` or `Equation~\eqref{eq:}` it prints me on some lines `Equa-tion (1.1)`, or something like that (it breaks the page-links). I'd like to prevent hyphenation there. For now I actually do not bother when other words will hyphenated, but for the sake of lazyness I set it to the whole document. Actually I also tried `\newcommand{\smartref}{\nohyphenate{Equation~\eqref{#1}}` (syntax not correct, but you get the idea) and it was the exactly same result as using hyphenate none on the whole document.

Comment: @Buni `\newcommand{\nhautoref}[1]{\mbox{\autoref{#1}}}`, if you *really* want badly typeset paragraphs: then `\nhautoref{eq:some}` won't be broken.

Comment: @egreg actually I tried both, also `\mbox`, with the same result: no hyphenation but the line exceeds its maximal length. (I check this with `\KOMAoptions{draft=on}`)

Comment: @Buni Of course paragraphs won't be typeset correctly if you place overlong “words” without hyphenation points. I see nothing bad in a couple of “Equa-tion (1.1)”. Wait until the text is in final form and look for hyphens you want to remove: the only way is rewording (but loading `microtype` helps in having less hyphens); if not possible, leave the “bad” hyphen.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use the packages `ragged2e` and `microtype`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum, ragged2e, microtype}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3.6cm,bottom=3.6cm,left=3.6cm,right=3.6cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\RaggedRight
%\raggedright
\lipsum[5]
\end{document}
```

You will see the difference, if you comment out `\RaggedRight` and uncomment `\raggedright`.